# Displaying product viewd report in dashboard in opencart

Tags: opencart

I want to display Product Viewed Report in Dashboard itself. Now the report id under Report->Products->Viewed

How to display it? I tried copying the code from admin->controller->report->product_viewed.php TO admin->controller->common->home.php

and copied the code from admin->view->report->product_viewed.tpl to admin->common->home.tpl

i have added code like this in home.tpl

```
<div class="content">
      <table class="list">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <td class="left"><?php echo $column_name; ?></td>
            <td class="left"><?php echo $column_model; ?></td>
            <td class="right"><?php echo $column_viewed; ?></td>
            <td class="right"><?php echo $column_percent; ?></td>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <?php if ($products) { ?>
          <?php foreach ($products as $product) { ?>
          <tr>
            <td class="left"><?php echo $product['name']; ?></td>
            <td class="left"><?php echo $product['model']; ?></td>
            <td class="right"><?php echo $product['viewed']; ?></td>
            <td class="right"><?php echo $product['percent']; ?></td>
          </tr>
          <?php } ?>
          <?php } else { ?>
          <tr>
            <td class="center" colspan="4"><?php echo $text_no_results; ?></td>
          </tr>
          <?php } ?>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      </div>
```

in my admin panel-> dashboard i am getting error like this

Notice: Undefined variable: products in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/opencart/admin/view/template/common/home.tpl on line 95Notice: Undefined variable: column_name in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/opencart/admin/view/template/common/home.tpl on line 88   Notice: Undefined variable: column_model in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/opencart/admin/view/template/common/home.tpl on line 89   Notice: Undefined variable: column_viewed in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/opencart/admin/view/template/common/home.tpl on line 90  Notice: Undefined variable: column_percent in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/opencart/admin/view/template/common/home.tpl on line 91

please help me in solving this? where i should declare this 'products' ?[image: This is the error i am getting]

Comment: Hello, please somebody help me in this plz

Comment: Did my answer work for you? If so please mark it correct and vote up :)

Answer (score 0):

What it looks like to me is that there are no results from the products viewed and you have done this transition almost perfectly.

You can either update the language files with the appropriate fields in admin>language>english>common>home.php or you can change the tpl a little like this

```
<div class="content">
  <table class="list">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td class="left">Product Name:</td>
        <td class="left">Model:</td>
        <td class="right">Viewed:</td>
        <td class="right">Percent:</td>
```